# DOB javascript regular expression partially working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on some kind of personal info validation via javascript in my project. I have used regular expression to handle most validation. But I am surprised about DOB validation.

The regular expression pattern is working for some value and nor working for few other although values format are same.

My Regular expression for DOB which accepts only YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/g
```

Value 1: 1912-12-12
Value 2: 2000-11-18

My javascript test function is return true for value 1 and returning false for value 2. I have also checked there is no space around values.

I have cross checked the same thing on below link:

[Regular Expression Tester Javascript](https://www.regextester.com/)

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with Value 2 or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `g` flag. FYI: if you plan to match a whole string add anchors, `/^[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/`

Comment: Can you please show the code where you use the regex ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for reply. I have also tried after removing "g" flag. But my concern is why the samething is working for Value 1 but not for Value 2? Format is same for both values.

Comment: [All explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520853/3832970)

Comment: @Pratham here is the code:    var valid = dob_format.test("2000-11-18");

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. you made my day.